# Conversion of decimal 5,0 into smallint in teradata sql assistant

Tags: teradata

I am trying to cast Decimal 5.0 into small integer.I am using following query but its not working.thanks in advance.
cast (a.mrktc_agen as  SMALLINT) as mrktc_agen

Answer (score 1):

"is not working" is not a very detailed error description :-)

There's probably a value outside of the valid range for a SMALLINT (-32768 to 32767) and you get a "Numeric overflow" error.